# undefined reference to vtable for

Tags: c++, abstract-class, bind, virtual

Basically, I'd like to create an interface (`C::doTask(double&)`) using a virtual base class (`A`) and let the user to create a concrete class(`B`). Inside the interface, I use std::bind to pass a virtual struct member function. When compiling the code, I got the error of `undefined reference to vtable for XXX`.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the header file `test.h`

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>


typedef std::function<double(double const &)> MyFun;

// base class
struct A
{
    double x;
    // other parameters
    A(){ x = 0.;};
    virtual ~A();
    virtual double fun(double const &x);
};

struct C
{
    MyFun myfun;
    void init(A &a)
    {
        using std::placeholders::_1;
        myfun = std::bind( &A::fun, a, _1 );
    }
    double doTask(double x)
    {
        // do something
        // call myfun 
        return 0.;
    }
};
```

Here is the `main` file `test.cpp`

```
#include<iostream>
#include "test.h"

// concrete class
struct B:A
{
    // define some other parameters as members
    double a,b;
    B()
    {
        a=1.;
        b=2.;
    }
    double fun(double const &x) override
    {
        return a+b+x;
    }
};


int main()
{
    B b;
    C c;
    c.init(b);

    c.doTask(0.5);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile `g++ --std=c++11 test.cpp` and I got:

```
/tmp/ccTmrVPi.o: In function `A::A()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN1AC2Ev[_ZN1AC5Ev]+0x9): undefined reference to `vtable for A'
/tmp/ccTmrVPi.o: In function `std::_Head_base<0ul, A, false>::~_Head_base()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZNSt10_Head_baseILm0E1ALb0EED2Ev[_ZNSt10_Head_baseILm0E1ALb0EED5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `A::~A()'
/tmp/ccTmrVPi.o: In function `A::A(A const&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN1AC2ERKS_[_ZN1AC5ERKS_]+0xd): undefined reference to `vtable for A'
/tmp/ccTmrVPi.o: In function `B::~B()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN1BD2Ev[_ZN1BD5Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `A::~A()'
/tmp/ccTmrVPi.o:(.rodata._ZTI1B[_ZTI1B]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for A'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: In particular, you forgot to define `~A`.

Comment: `fun` has to be defined as well (`std::bind` doesn't seem to like it being pure virtual).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you mean I cannot bind a virtual function? `fun` is virtual and can it be defined in the base class?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I added `virtual ~A() = default;` and still got the same error. Is this a simple way to define `~A`?

Comment: You also forgot to define `fun`. `virtual ~A() = default;` is inline again, so now the vtable gets attached to `fun`, but that's more of an implementation detail.